# Encrypt communication with wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to create a secure communication between my console application and the WCF service. I am currently using `basichttpbinding`, so the data could be suspected in case of a MIM attack. The only thing I care about is that the data cannot be seen by an attacker.

A very simple method seems to be to manually encrypt the data before sending it to the service and decrypt it with the same key on the service. Until the attacker knows the key he will not be able to decrypt the message.

I'm sure there is an easier way to do it. While reading the internet I came across information about using HTTPS for WCF communication. I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl, so I created a certificate, and this is how my WCF service web.config file looks like:

```cs
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="wsservice.Service1">
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                      contract="wsservice.IService1"/>

            <endpoint address="mex"
                      binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

However, the problem is that when I query the service from the console application, I get the following error:

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

I can solve it with this workaround:

```cs
private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

But I don't like it very much, I would have to add something like this in every application that communicates with the service. Isn't there any easier way around this problem?

Comment: From a configuration standpoint, the easy work-around is to use a valid certificate - one issued by a public certificate authority. If your traffic is on a private network, it’s hard to think of a simpler work-around than what you’ve already discovered.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'm very surprised that there isn't some built-in function that encrypts the wcf message using some key, and then using the same key decrypts it on the other side. The same key would have to point in both the client and the server. A very simple method that would provide a bit more security (at least against a MIM attack)

Comment: WCF services (and configuration) are tedious and (tbh) outdated. You could add a compiler directive to only include this workaround in debug environments, but @500-InternalServerError is correct - a valid certificate will solve your issues.

Comment: @riffnl so lets say you create wcf service that is available in your local network of your company. Really there is no easy solution to encrypt traffic that goes from employees to service?

Comment: @riffnl it seems to me that there must by some way to encrypt the data before it is sent (with a simple key) and decrypt it as soon as it reaches the service (and the same in the other way).

Comment: This error is because your server certificate is self-signed or the hostname you are connecting to is incorrect, you can refer to these posts for answers.https://github.com/IdentityModel/AuthorizationServer/issues/23 and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d17b50ce-f341-4374-9725-7f3d6aad222e/svcutil-error-remote-certificate-invalid-according-to-validation-procedure?forum=wcf

Comment: @LanHuang so what I can do about it? Lets say you have 2 pc in your lan network. First hosts wcf service, and second is running console app which exchange data with that service. You want to somehow encrypt data to provide some security. You can't use self-signed certificate, so what do you do?

Comment: You need to install the certificate on the client computer's Trusted Root Certification Authorities and make it trusted by all users, you can check the link I provided.